# Call json file using jQuery / ajax pasing parameter

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

Just want to ask how to call json file with parameter?

Previously, I've been using php and convert to json.

Here is jQuery script:

```
$("#btnKeyword").on("click",function(){

    var param = document.getElementById('inputKeyword').value;

    alert(param);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "./php/scr1.php",
        data:{ keyword: param},
        success: function (data) {

            for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            var no = i+1;
            $table ="<tr class='row-parent' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>";
            $table += "<td align='right'>"+no+ "</td>";
            $table += "<td  class='id'>"+data[i].uid+ "</td>";
            $table += "<td>"+data[i].document_id+ "</td>";
            $table += "<td>"+data[i].activity+ "</td>";
            $table += "<td>"+data[i].date_time+ "</td>";
            $table +="</tr>";

            $("#docLoc").append($table);
            }               
        },error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {alert("ERROR:" + xhr.responseText+" - "+thrownError);}
    });
});
```

My json file 2.json.

How to do condition in json file

```
[

{

    "id": "7",
    "uid": "287",
    "document_id": "X85BMaJe6,",
    "activity": "2",
    "date_time": "10-12-2015 17:29:04"

},
{

    "id": "9",
    "uid": "288",
    "document_id": "X85BMxJe6,",
    "activity": "2",
    "date_time": "15-12-2015 09:59:49"

},

    {
        "id": "11",
        "uid": "289",
        "document_id": "X45CMxJe6,",
        "activity": "2",
        "date_time": "17-12-2015 15:16:04"
    }

]
```

Hope this can help

Thanks in advance for helping me..

Answer (score 0):

A json file is a static resource and unless you use a programming language on server to read it and deliver it it will always be a static resource.

If you want to filter results from that file in browser you need to use array methods like `Array.prototype.filter()` or `Array.prototype.map()` or `Array.prototype.some()` etc to do it with your javascript

Comment: i did not get the idea, sorry about that.can you give an example

Comment: Not very clear what you are trying to do to be honest. What was wrong with your php approach? What are your higher level goals? etc